# What are the pros and cons of using iTunes to manage my iPod?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, ipod

I've heard people talking about using alternative software to manage their iPods.

My iPod came in the post today and I was wondering what the pros and cons of using iTunes (as opposed to popular alternative) were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pros: All works. Easy to use. Easy to Configure. Does Backups of your data. Allows iTS purchases. Handles everything for you. And every other iTunes feature that you might consider important (AirTunes for example).

Cons: iTunes might be a “heavy” application for some machines with limited RAM. Even if all you want is a music player, iTunes is all or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Itunes is far more integrated than anything you could imagine if you haven't used it with a music device, but on the other hand syncing is hardly necessary any more, you can do most operations over the net.

If you just want to manually dump a bunch of songs and movies onto your iThingy once in a while it doesn't matter much what you use, but if you are into regular synching with your computer and want it to manage music, movies and apps (backup, etc) as well as backing up your entire iDevice regularly then iTunes is really the only choice.

I guess I'd go with the non-apple solution first, give it a try for a month or so, then go 100% itunes (let it sync music, etc) for a bit.  Compare and contrast.  Shouldn't hurt too much to switch.